# Laravel 5 Custom Fatal Error Exception

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, laravel-5, fatal-error

I am building a web service in Laravel 5. However if there's a fatal error, Laravel always return the generic 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong' page.

How can change it to return JSON / XML instead?

Note

- I know that you can put other exception in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` but this doesn't work for Fatal Error Exception
- I read for Laravel 4 you can do `App::fatal(function(){...})` Is this still the valid way to do in Laravel 5? If yes where should I put it?

Thanks heaps